# Given a string, find a row with whose value the string starts

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I got a variable in bash, for exemple `test=CCA123`.

Assume I have a table named `init` with a column `name` in my MySQL database. The table contains the following values.

**name:**

- CC
- CCB
- AA
- AZ
- AZE
- AQS

Given this, I want an SQL that would select `CC`.

So, I want something like this:

```
mysql -u USER -pPASS -D DATABASE -e "SELECT name FROM intit WHERE $test LIKE name%`
```

But of course, that doesn't work! Any idea of how can i do that?

Comment: if test was CCB123, which row would you want and why?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
"SELECT name FROM intit WHERE name LIKE \"$test%\""
```

Comment: I already try but it's not working because it's not $test who need a wildcard but my line from sql...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the expression you want:

```
select name
from init
where '$test' like concat('test=', name, '%');
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use an index and `name` is always two or three characters:

```
select name
from init
where name = left(substring_index('$test', '=', -1), 2) or
      name = left(substring_index('$test', '=', -1), 3);
```

Comment: About your first option I just tried but mysql tell me that 'CCA123' is not a column... I think first part of the where clause need to be a column..

Comment: And for the other one, it's not perfect for me but I tried and, without the quote around the $test, he told me CCA123 is not a column, and with quotes, he told me there is a syntax error.... (it's the same with escaped double quotes  and simple quotes)

Comment: never mind, i just retried you second approach and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pierro06 . . . I put quotes around `$test`, but you should really be adding it in as a parameter.